# Coordinating auto-gensym in nested syntax-quotes in Clojure

Tags: clojure, gensym

In Clojure, you need to use `gensym` to create symbols for internal use in your macros to keep them hygienic. However, sometimes you need to use the same symbol in nested syntax-quotes. For example, if I want to bind a value to a symbol with `let` and print it three times in an unrolled loop, I'd do

```
`(let [x# 1]
   ~@(repeat 3
             `(println x#)))
```

But that would produce

```
(clojure.core/let [x__2__auto__ 1]
                  (clojure.core/println x__1__auto__)
                  (clojure.core/println x__1__auto__)
                  (clojure.core/println x__1__auto__))
```

`x#` generates a different symbol in the `let` form than in the `println` forms nested within it - because they were created from different syntax-quotes.

To solve it, I can generate the symbol beforehand and inject it to the syntax-quotes:

```
(let [x (gensym)]
  `(let [~x 1]
     ~@(repeat 3
               `(println ~x)))
)
```

This will produce the correct result, with the same symbol everywhere needed:

```
(clojure.core/let [G__7 1]
                  (clojure.core/println G__7)
                  (clojure.core/println G__7)
                  (clojure.core/println G__7))
```

Now, while it does produce the right result, the code itself looks ugly and verbose. I don't like having to "declare" a symbol, and the injection syntax makes it look like it came from outside the macro, or calculated somewhere within in it. I want to be able to use the auto-gensym syntax, which makes it clear that those are macro-internal symbols.

So, is there any way to use auto-gensym with nested syntax-quotes and make them produce the same symbol?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Auto-gensym'd symbols are only valid within the syntax-quote that defines them and they don't work in unquoted code because that is not part of the syntax quote.

Here the symbol `x#` gets replaced by it's gensym because it is within the scope of the syntax quote:

```
core> `(let [x# 1] x#)
(clojure.core/let [x__1942__auto__ 1] x__1942__auto__)
```

And if you unquote it it no longer gets translated into it's syntax quote:

```
core> `(let [x# 1] ~@x#)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: x# in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

Auto-gensyms are a very convenient shortcut within the syntax-quote, everywhere else you apparently need to use `gensym` directly as is the case with your later example.

there are other ways to structure this macro so autogensyms will work though declaring gensymed symbols in a let at the top of a macro is very normal in Clojure and other lisps as well.

Comment: Thanks. I can't get normal-quoting the print expression to work, but I suppose it'll become cumbersome for more complex macros anyways...

Comment: If you do something like this, I strongly recommend using \`println, not 'println - the former is not subject to name-capture in case the macro user has an unusual namespace or lexical context.

Comment: @IdanArye sorry, it was not working because my answer was wrong :-( I added a hopefully correct edit

Answer (score 9):

Your method (calling gensym) is the right one.

However in some cases you can get by with a clever use of `doto`, `->` or `->>`. See:

```
 `(let [x# 1]
   (doto x#
     ~@(repeat 3 `println)))
```

Comment: I actually thought about using `doto`, but failed to find the command - I was looking for something along the lines of `dowith`, because that's what I'm used to from other languages...

Answer (score 1):

More generally you can do the following whenever faced with this situation:

```clj
(let [x `x#]
   `(let [~x 1]
      ~@(repeat 3
                `(println ~x))))
```

To be clear, you create the auto-gensym and bind it outside of the syntax-quoted form, and then inside any nested forms which require it you can just use syntax-unquote.